# powershell - create new subfolder if another subfolder exists

Tags: batch-file, powershell, subdirectory

im trying to create a powershell to create a new subfolder in 200+ parent folders but only if another folder exists in the parent folder. My script so far is below, no errors, but it wont work... any help would be good.

```
$foldername = "Folder1"
$sourceFolder = "C:\x\y\z"
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem  -Directory $sourceFolder)) {
if (!$foldername) 
md FolderA
}
```

---

OK, ive started from scratch. I can now create 'FolderB' in all the subfolders, but i cant get it to NOT create 'FolderB' if 'FolderA' does not exist.

```
$root = "\\server\folder1"

ForEach ($dir in (Get-Item -Path "$root\*\" | ?{$_.PSIsContainer})){

If (!(Test-Path -Path "\*\FolderA")) {

    New-Item -Path "$root\*\" -Name "FolderB" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what you're after but maybe something like this?

```
ls $sourceFolder -Directory                         # get all directories
    | ? { Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName $folderName) -PathType Container } # where a directory path of this folder+folderName exists
    | % { mkdir (Join-Path $_.FullName FolderA) } #build up a path and make that directory
```

Not sure if this will work if broken up on multiple lines, you might have to put it all on one line or put a ` at the end of a line to force it

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt being clear... what im trying to work out is how to create 'FolderA' in multiple folders if they have a path of \\server\folder1\folder2\ .... and create FolderA at Folder2's level. But skip if path is only \\server\folder1\